# Latex table not showing vertical lines

Tags: tables, tabularx

can someone tell me why my vertical lines are stopping after the 1 and the first part of text
[image]

this is the code is used:

```
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
    \hline
        constants&value&context\\
        \hline
        C1&1& \multirow{9}{0.8\textwidth}{These three constants are specifically designed to address the total profit objective and serve as scaling factors for the cost and revenue aspects.The first constant, C1, is set to 1 since the actual apartment values are already incorporated into the revenue equation. The remaining two constants are introduced to ensure that when the real values are plugged into the equations alongside these constants, the total sum equates to 70 million euros. In this context, C1 accounts for the revenue, while the other two constants are used to approximate both the construction time and material expenses, each approximating around 35 million euros.}
        \\\\\\
        \cline{1-2}
        C2&10\\
        \\\\
        \cline{1-2}
        C3&50\\
        \\\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: you have `\\ \\ ` which ends a row short with just the first column, so no vertical lines after the first cell. If you _really_ want a blank row use `\\ & & \\ ` so you have three empty cells

Answer (score 2):

I think you should redesign the table so that the material that's currently occupying the right-hand column becomes a text block of its own.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
        \hline
        Constant & Value  \\ \hline
        C1 & \phantom{0}1 \\
        C2 & 10 \\
        C3 & 50 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center} 
These three constants are specifically designed to address the total profit objective and serve as scaling factors for the cost and revenue aspects. The first constant, C1, is set to 1 since the actual apartment values are already incorporated into the revenue equation. The remaining two constants are introduced to ensure that when the real values are plugged into the equations alongside these constants, the total sum equates to 70 million euros. In this context, C1 accounts for the revenue, while the other two constants are used to approximate both the construction time and material expenses, each approximating around 35 million euros.
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

For your table I would use `tblr` of `tabularray` package. Using it code is simple, short and gives nice result:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
    \begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
                 colspec = {l l X[cmd=\RaggedRight]},
                 cell{2}{3} = {r=3}{},  % for multi row cell
                 vspan=even
                 }

constants   & value & context   \\
C1          & 1     &   These three constants are specifically designed to address the total profit objective and serve as scaling factors for the cost and revenue aspects.The first constant, C1, is set to 1 since the actual apartment values are already incorporated into the revenue equation. The remaining two constants are introduced to ensure that when the real values are plugged into the equations alongside these constants, the total sum equates to 70 million euros. In this context, C1 accounts for the revenue, while the other two constants are used to approximate both the construction time and material expenses, each approximating around 35 million euros. \\
C2          & 10    &   \\  
C3          & 50    &   \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

**remarks:**

- in table you may consider to use in ˙\small` font size
- since you not provide any information about your document, table in it may has a bit different looks (last column can be wider or shorter).